# Is $\frac{1}{x}$ continuosly differentiable on the set $E = (- \infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, continuity, initial-value-problems

Just to explain the motivation behind some other thing, I shall ask first this question:

> Is $\frac{1}{x}$ continuosly differentiable (or we can examine
>   $\frac{1}{x^3}$ also) on the set  $$E = (- \infty, 0) \cup (0,
> > \infty)$$

The reason why I'm asking this is that when we consider a solution to a given initial value problem, we define the definition of interval of that solution as a single connected set (or just an interval), and the reason for this is explained to me as that we are trying to find solutions $y(x) \in C^1$, but when I discard the problematic points from my domain, why should I get any problem about the condition that $y \in C^1$ ?

**Edit:**

For example, let say that we solve an ODE, and the general solution is of the form 
$$y(x) = c / x.$$
Then if the initial condition is given as $y(1) = 1$, we see that $c = 1$, and the domain of definition is $1 \in (0,\infty)$. However, I do not understand the motivation behind the reason why the interval of definition is not $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ .

Comment: My answer address your edit exactly. The issue is uniqueness.

Comment: @symplectomorphic see my comments please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $1/x$ and $1/x^3$ are continuously differentiable (in fact, infinitely differentiable) on your domain (the set of all nonzero reals).

The reason we typically assume that the domain of a solution to an IVP is connected is to ensure uniqueness. If you try to solve the IVP $f'(x)=-1/x^2$ with $f(1)=1$ on your domain, the solution isn't unique: the values of the function aren't determined in the left half-plane.

Comment: how does the connectedness related with the uniqueness ? I mean is there any theorem about this ?

Comment: I have only seen existance and uniqueness for the first order linear ODEs.

Comment: Yes, there is a general theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem

Comment: The point is that the solution is only uniquely determined *locally*. The initial condition may not determine the solution *globally*, as in your example: knowing $f(1)=1$ is not enough to determine the values when $x<0$.

Comment: I see, thank for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The funciton $f(x)=\frac1x$ is an element of $C^1(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$.

To comment on your question about the initial value problems, I would need more information about what is unclear to you.

Comment: see my edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is inadequate. The function is in $C^1(E)$. It is also in $C^1(U)$ for every interval $U\subset E$. You must specify the domain in this notation if it isn’t implicit, especially when you are considering several of them.
In other words, $C^1$ without a specified domain is ambiguous.